# merging and visualization of datasets using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

For example, i  have the following data frame in pandas cleaned and ready for merging.

```
DataFrame1 for average Income per year

Country | Year 1  | Year 2  | Year 3
  A     |   50    |   30    |   20
  B     |   70    |   20    |   90
  C     |   10    |   20    |   30

Dataframe2 for Fertility rate 

Country | Year 1 | Year 2 | Year 3
   A    |   1.5  |   2    |  2.5
   B    |   2    |   2    |   3
   C    |   1    |   1    |   4
```

Basically im trying to show the relationship between DataFrame1 and DataFrame2 over the years on matplotlib. But i cant seem to merge them as they have the same headings as Years? In addition, i just cant seem to find a graph for me to compare these data on matplotlib when trying to use the X axis as the years.Any advice wold be great as im using the values above as the datasets are huge. Could it be that the data is too much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider generating separate country plots with a secondary axis since you are tracking two metrics of different scales: *Income* and *Fertility*. For this setup, you will need to reshape your wide format to long with `pandas.melt()`. Then, iterate through the distinct countries to filter the data frames.

**Data**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                    'Year 1': [50, 70, 10],
                    'Year 2': [30, 20, 20],
                    'Year 3': [20, 90, 30]})

df1 = df1.melt(id_vars='Country', value_name='Income', var_name='Year')

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                    'Year 1': [1.5, 2, 1],
                    'Year 2': [2.0, 2, 1],
                    'Year 3': [2.5, 3, 4]})

df2 = df2.melt(id_vars='Country', value_name='Fertility', var_name='Year')
```

**Plot**

```
for c in df1['Country'].unique():
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    df1[df1['Country']==c].plot(kind='line', x='Year', y='Income', ax=ax1, color='g', legend=False)
    df2[df2['Country']==c].plot(kind='line', x='Year', y='Fertility', ax=ax2, color='b', legend=False)

    plt.title('Country ' + c)
    ax1.set_xlabel('Years')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Average Income Per Year')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Fertility Rate')

    lines = ax1.get_lines() + ax2.get_lines()
    ax1.legend(lines, [l.get_label() for l in lines], loc='upper left')

    ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(3))
    ax1.set_xticklabels(df1["Year"].unique())

    plt.show()
    plt.clf()

plt.close()
```

[image: Plot Output]